# .click isn't working with an anchour inside a figure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a figure that is loaded by a JavaScript code this figure contain an image description and two buttons, sometimes the description has an anchor with an attribute called fig, see bellow.

```
<a fig="allow" href="#tt5">[1]</a>
```

now if the anchor is not within a figure and the attribute fig is allow, JS will create a figure by adding a class attribute = pop-up and this figure will be displayed beneath the link so the anchor will look like this:

```
<a class="pop-up" fig="allow" href="tt5">[o]</a>
```

But in my case the anchour is inside a figure so i need to just close the figure but it seems that .click and .live aren't working.

here is what I've tried:

1. Using `.live()` :

   ```
   $viewer.find('div > div > span.Figcontent > a').live('click',function() {
        toggleViewerCaption();
   });
   ```
2. Using .click

   ```
   $viewer.find('div > div > span.Figcontent > a').click(function(){
       toggleViewerCaption();
   });
   ```

**Note :**

1. I've made sure that the above is accessing the right anchor by testing this in console and it returned `tt5`.
2. The debugger doesn't hit the break points on the syntax above even tho the console is returning the right value.

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML?

Comment: the link may be under (the other element covering it e.g. z-index ) a div or any element which preventing the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've a figure that is loaded by a JavaScript code...

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** since you deal with DOM generated dynamically :

```
$viewer.on("click", "div > div > span.Figcontent > a", function(){
    toggleViewerCaption(); 
});
```

**NOTE :**

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This and also you should not use find if you're not sure when the element is added to the dom. Instead, something like this: $viewer.on("click", "div > div > span.Figcontent a", function(){
    toggleViewerCaption();
});

Comment: @JuhaTauriainen you are 100% right that was the cause of the problem in the fist place, could you please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not use find if you're not sure when the element is added to the dom.

Instead, something like this:

```
$viewer.on("click", "div > div > span.Figcontent a", function() {
  toggleViewerCaption();
});
```